# Initializing class member with parameterized constructor - Compiler thinks I'm declaring a function?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to initialize a class member, where in which the member is an instance of another class. Visual studio seems to think I'm declaring a function member:

```
class OtherClass {
    OtherClass();
    OtherClass(string Foo);
}

class MainClass {
    // This Compiles. Default constructor used
    OtherClass Instance1;

    // Does not compile. Visual studio thinks I'm declaring a function member that returns an OtherClass. 
    OtherClass Instance2("Foobar");
}
```

I realize that I can accomplish what I want with a member initialization list like so:

```
class MainClass {
    OtherClass Instance2;

    MainClass() : Instance2("Foobar") {}
}
```

I'm just confused by the fact that, in the first example, the compiler understands that I'm initializing an OtherClass member when I use the default constructor, but it thinks I'm declaring a function if I try to use the constructor that expects a string. Could someone please explain the reasoning behind this and if there is another work-around I'm unaware of?

Update: This declaration ambiguity has a name: [Most Vexing Parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An in-class member initializer must either use an equal sign or `{`curly braces`}`.

So:

```
OtherClass Instance2 = "Foobar";
```

or:

```
OtherClass Instance2{ "Foobar" };
```

Comment: Ahh I didn't know of that rule. Thank you so much!!